# Python CGI, FieldStorage and javascript array

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, cgi

I searched and searched, and I am certain there is a simple answer. However, the solution escapes me. I have javascript that takes all

elements and puts the id attribute into an array, then sends it to an apache http server. Then, using python, the data is supposed to be retrieved, made into a python list, then iterated.

My problem is that I can't seem to get an iterable list. Here is the output from FieldStorage:

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('data', '[["NWS-IDP-PROD-KEEPALIVE-30678","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426831","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426829-2276816","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426827-2276815","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426823-2276812","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426824-2276814","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426823-2276811","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426823-2276813","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426822-2276809","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426822-2276810","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426822-2276808","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426822-2276807","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426821","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426819-2276806","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426818-2276805","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426817-2276804","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426815-2276801","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426816-2276803","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426813-2276800","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426807-2276797","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426806-2276796","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426805-2276795","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426803-2276793","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426802-2276792","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426800-2276791","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426796-2276787","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426797-2276789","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426793-2276785","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426792-2276784","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426787-2276779","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426791-2276783","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426783-2276775","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426785-2276777","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426784-2276776","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426789-2276781","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426788-2276780","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426786-2276778","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426790-2276782","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426781-2276773","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426779-2276771","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426778-2276770","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426777-2276769","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426774-2276766","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426768-2276762","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426764-2276760","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426758-2276751","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426757-2276750","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426756-2276749","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426754-2276747","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426755-2276748","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426753-2276746","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426752-2276745","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426750-2276743","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426749-2276742","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426748-2276741","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426747-2276740","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426743-2276736","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426744-2276737","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426746-2276739","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426745-2276738","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426538-2276561","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426539-2276562","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426536-2276559","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426535-2276558","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426502-2276526","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426501-2276525","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426495-2276519","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426490-2276514","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426494-2276518","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426493-2276517","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426492-2276516","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426487-2276512","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426484-2276509","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426483-2276508","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426479-2276504","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426477-2276503","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426475-2276502","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426458-2276486","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426453-2276482","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426452-2276481","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426450-2276480","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426442-2276474","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426437-2276470","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426438-2276471","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426433-2276466","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426432-2276465","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426434-2276467","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426430-2276463","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426431-2276464","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426203-2276345","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426204-2276346","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426102-2276282","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426052-2276244","NWS-IDP-PROD-2426019-2276228","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425905-2276157","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425891-2276153","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425874-2276146","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425851-2276136","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425801-2276114","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425748-2276070","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425747-2276069","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425746-2276068","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425745-2276067","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425744-2276066","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425743-2276065","NWS-IDP-PROD-2425681-2276015","NWS-IDP-PROD-2424738-2275345","NWS-IDP-PROD-2421587-2272709","NWS-IDP-PROD-2419354-2270782"]]')])
```

And the javascript code:

```
mkTableArray: function() {
    var myTableArray = [];
    $("#alerts").each(function() {
        var arrayOfThisRow = [];
        var tableData = $(this).find('li');
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            tableData.each(function() {
                arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).attr("id"));
            });
            myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
        }
    });
    var myJson = JSON.stringify(myTableArray);
    return myJson;
}

function fetchNewAlerts() {
    data = Alert.mkTableArray();

    $.post( "fetchNew.py", {data}, function(data) {
        $("#alerts").prepend(data);
        $(".new").hide().fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
```

And the python:

```
data = cgi.FieldStorage()
mfs = data.getvalue("data")
print(mfs)
for line in mfs:
  print(line)
```

Python is treating the entire thing as one list item. So doing a, for x in y loop, only prints out what you see above. It's treating it as though all of the items in the list are actually one single item. And I do not know how, or I have not yet figured out how, to get each NWS-IDP-PROD-2426826 item, separately so I can test each iteration. I have tried .split(), but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I must have had a brain lapse. I was able to accomplish my goal by doing this:

```
data = cgi.FieldStorage()

print ("Content-Type: text/html")
print ()



mfs = data.getvalue("data")

lines = mfs.split(",")

for feature in nwsJson:
    if feature['properties']['id'] not in lines:
        pass
    else:
        print("<li>" +feature['properties']['id']+ "</li>")
```